# Magento not sending emails

Tags: email, cron, ce-1.9.1.0, email-scheduler

I have a problem with the system sending Magento . Do not want to send e -mail order confirmation (e- mails about the account is sent ) . When you refresh a cron job in my web browser , these emails are sent , but I wish it would happen automatically. I installed the program sheulder which shows that the e- mails are stuck in the queue and do not want to leave. I would ask you to explain the process of how to fix this for a beginner .

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't by now, please set up a cron job on your server which calls `<magento_root>/cron.sh` every 5 minutes or less. That will cause all emails to be sent.

I had a similar issue where many emails were being sent (for some reason they weren't queued) but others just didn't get out until I set up cron the right way.

If you are on Linux, just add this line to your crontab file, which you can access via the Linux command `crontab -e`

> */5 * * * *  /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.sh

For more information about other operating systems and cron's role in Magento, check [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job#dokuwiki__top) site.

If you get errors regarding `/proc`, comment out the lines in `cron.sh` which check whether the process is already running.

Comment: I still don't know what i should do. In magento system option i have seted evry 5 minutes but it dont still work. I have outside server, not in my home and i dont have acces to it. Only through ftp

Comment: @Yardi do me a favor and reread my answer. You need a cron job on your server system, has not much to do with Magento. That cron job will execute a file from magento which takes care of all jobs to be done. 
Once you read my answer again, are you on linux or windows or something else?

Comment: I working on windows, but my server is i think on linux but i dont have acces to it. I dont have cron.js too. Only in main folder i have cron.sh and cron.php. I try to set up on my server but i have that messenages: Could not open input file: /home/warmit/ftp:/WarmIT/cron.php Could not open input file: /home/warmit/ftp:/WarmIT/cron.sh

Comment: @Yardi, sorry, it's cron.sh, typo. Please contact your hoster, usually they will allow you to set up cron jobs. Otherwise you need a script which accesses yourdomain/cron.php every minute, that will do the same. Either execute cron.sh via a cron job or send a request to the URL cron.php. For a quick solution you can also just go there with your browser, but dont forget to automate it because else no emails will be sent when you don't visit that URL frequently

Comment: Setting up a cronjob that executes cron.php every minute is not a good idea. You can do that with cron.sh but not the php version, since it doesn't guard against multiple instances being invoked. If you invoke cron.php, use [flock(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock). I realize this confuses the original poster even more, yet, many sites have totally wrecked indexes, stock amounts or failed imports have their root cause in overlapping cron.php runs.

Comment: # location of the php binary
if [ ! "$1" = "" ] ; then
    CRONSCRIPT=$1
else
    CRONSCRIPT=cron.php
fi

MODE=""
if [ ! "$2" = "" ] ; then
        MODE=" $2"
fi

PHP_BIN=`which php`

Comment: PHP_BIN=`which php`

# absolute path to magento installation
INSTALLDIR=`echo $0 | sed 's/cron\.sh//g'`

#       prepend the intallation path if not given an absolute path
if [ "$INSTALLDIR" != "" -a "`expr index $CRONSCRIPT /`" != "1" ];then
    if ! ps auxwww | grep "$INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
else
    if  ! ps auxwww | grep "$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep | grep -v cron.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then

Comment: $PHP_BIN $CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
fi

Comment: This is what i recive after start cron.sh, but it still don't sending emails. If i try cron.php, i didn't recive any messenage and still no send.

Comment: At last i make it good with help from server support. Now i waiting for respond from them, but maybe somebody from there know the answer. Last error is: Error, do this: mount -t proc none /proc

Comment: @Yardi please see my edit

Comment: Ok. It works at now evry 10 minutest server doing it automatically. Thanks

Comment: @Yardi please feel free to accept my answer using the tick underneath the upvote if it helped you