# Order emails not sending to Sales Representative (store email address)

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email, ce-1.9.1.1

I have ce 1.9.1.1 installed and it appears that all of the emails are sending except for the Order notification email to the set "Sales Representative" email set up in System>Configuration>Store Email Addresses.

I'm running Linux CPanel virtual hosting (customer's choice) through Godaddy, I have a cron job set up to run every minute pointed at cron.php, their company email is through google business apps and I have the MX records set up correctly for that.

It sends the order invoice to the customer email address, the contact form works, and if I put an email address in the "Send order copy email to:" field in System>Configuration>Sales Emails and set it as "Send Order Email Copy Method" to "Separate Email" it will send the order notification to that email address.

So to summarize:  When and order is placed on front end, the customer receives an email and whatever email address is put into the Send Order Email Copy receives an email, but no matter what email address is put in as the Sales Representative email (whether in domain or different domain) it does not send an email to Sales Representative.

What am I missing?

Comment: if you add a second email address there, a yahoo one for example, does it work? `yours@domainname.com, second@yahoo.com`

Comment: It doesn't allow you to parse multiple email addresses into the Store Email Addresses fields, however, I did the following test:

Sales Representative Email:  google1@gmail.com
Customer Account Email:  google2@gmail.com
Send Copy to (separate email) jeremiah@customerdomain.com, google3@gmail.com

The only email that was not received was the Order Notification to Sales Representative "google1@gmail.com"  I can change that to ANY email address and it will not send to whatever email address I put into that field.

Comment: Basically, I can put any email address I want in for the customer account email and the Send Copy To fields and it will send those, but no matter what email is set up in Store Email Addresses > Sales Representative, it will not send orders to that address.  And a preemptive "Yes" to all the order notifications are set to send to Sales Representative :)

Comment: I've been using Send Order Email Copy To as a work around so the client receives order notifications but we would both like to resolve this the way it was intended to be used.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This might be an "Oh Duh!" moment, but is it SUPPOSED to send an order confirmation to the Sales Representative email, or is that just so it knows what email address to include in outgoing emails?

Comment: Have you tried if that email address is working? Probably just send email to that address from your gmail/hotmail/yahoo email to see if it is actually working.

Comment: The email addresses are working, all other system emails send to it and all other addresses I put into the field.   

I'm pretty sure I'm just being an idiot here and answered my own question.  I thought that it automatically sent order notifications to the Sales Representative "store email address".   When I went back and looked at Sales Email fields... It actually asks you which SENDER you want to choose from a drop-down, which leads me to believe that you have to use the Send Separate Copy field in order to receive order notifications internally.

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento not sending emails](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53752/magento-not-sending-emails)

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate sections that handle the Magento emails:

1. Store Email Addresses define addresses for senders of mails sent by the system.  (General, Sales, Support)
2. Sales Emails define which emails are sent and by which sender (as well as sending a copy to an admin if you would like to receive one).
3. System->Configuration->General->Store Email Addresses are only the sender addresses that will appear in the emails sent.  These fields have nothing to do with admins receiving emails or order notifications.  It's just a place to define sender email/return address for the system to use in the header. General Sales, Sales Representative, Support, etc.
4. System->Configuration->Sales->Sales Emails is where you configure which of the Store Email addresses you specified in the Store Email Addresses section will be the sender of New Orders, Comments, Invoices, etc.  By default, customers receive new order emails from the Sales Representative email address defined under Store Email Addresses

Sales Emails is where you configure the system to send a copy of an order to you as the admin, under (Send Order Email Copy To:)

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to my own question, but I was just reminded this post exists via email.

The issue is that the cron job that was setup to dispatch system emails was not ported over when the client paid for a site migration from GoDaddy to Siteground.

After setting up a cron job, emailing works as intended.

The following link addresses this issue:  http://trive.digital/blog/magento-emails-not-sent